# Wordpress doesn't respect Page slug in custom post type url pagination. Keeps getting removed

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination, slug

I have a custom post type, Company, with respective company child pages.

Whenever I attempt to go to a page url eg. http://example.com/company/example_company/page/2, the /page/2/ gets striped from the url. ?page=X also gets removed. This occurs regardless of the page query I'm using.

Other query vars are respected.

Debugging reveals the current page number is 0, other parts of the queries work fine.

/page/X works as expected on other archive pages

Comment: Pagination pattern for singular posts is `/slug/post-name/2/`, without `/page/`

Comment: Great. It doesn't get stripped out. But now I need to find out how to best grab that final slug.